# Python + BeautifulSoup: Encoding Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, beautifulsoup

If I run this code:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    href = str(href)
```

I'm getting the following error in the last line

```
href = str(href)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I try to encode the variable, as shown below:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    href = href.encode('utf-8')
    href = str(href)
```

I get the following error:

```
href = href.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I've looked at multiple posts in here and elsewhere, but none of them provided a suitable solution. I'm fairly new to python. Please help.

Comment: You can use a try/catch to print the value that is leading to error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever faces this issue, here's how I resolved it:

Ideally, for the encoding issue, this should've worked:

```
href = href.encode('utf-8')
href = str(href)
```

But in the set of webpages I was scrubbing, there were a few pages which didn't store any value in `href` variable, resulting in a few NoneType returns. And that was failing the `str(href)` statement. So I finally did this:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href is None:
        href = ""
    href = str(href.encode('utf-8'))
```

If `href` is a `NoneType`, its best to assign it to an empty string to prevent any type specific issue further in the code.

One of the observations I've made about the u\2018 and u\2019 characters, is that more often than not, they don't occur in the link itself, but in the attribute attached to the links. Which is generally the text after `?attribute=`. So if attributes are not important in your scrubbing, using a statement like the one below could solve all your problems.

```
href = href.split("?")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my native language we have a lot of "áçéàó" characters, so I frequently found myself in a similar situation, and most of the decoding/encoding tips didn't worked all the way.

Found my way out reseting the sys default language at the begining of my code using:

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
```

Hope this can also help with your problem.

Comment: thank you... I've already tried this and the UTF-8 as the default encoding. None of them have worked.